# Mongodb update array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a document to Mongodb update array of objects like this:

```
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "quizzes" : [
     { "wk" : 1, "score" : 10 },
     { "wk" : 2, "score" : 8 },
     { "wk" : 5, "score" : 8 }
  ]
}
```

And I want to add new field in each object of quizzes array. 
The expected result should be

```
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "quizzes" : [
     { "wk" : 1, "score" : 10, "day": 1 },
     { "wk" : 2, "score" : 8, "day": 2 },
     { "wk" : 5, "score" : 8, "day": 3 }
  ]
}

Any solution for this.
```

Comment: how will you decide the order of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$quizzes",
            includeArrayIndex: "quizzes.day"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            quizzes: { 
                $push: {
                    "score" : "$quizzes.score",
                    "wk" : "$quizzes.wk",
                    "day" : { $add: [ "$quizzes.day", 1 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "col"
    }
])
```

To assign indexes to each element you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with `includeArrayIndex` option. Those indexes start with `0` so we have to use `$add` to start with `1`. Then you can group back by your `_id` property and use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to save aggregation results to your collection.

Comment: can I do it without $project

Comment: @DineshSathrasala without $project you'll get 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3 however you can move that logic into $group like in edited answer